# not equal condition does not work in azure pipeline template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a condition to run a task in azure job template conditionally if value of parameter is not null, however the task runs even if value of parameter is null.

```
parameters:
- name: 'new_tag_value'
  default: ''
  type: string

  - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Update Image tag in helm chart'
      inputs:
        targetType: filePath
        filePath: '${{ parameters.bash_script_path_image_tag_update }}'
        arguments: '${{ parameters.new_tag_value }} ${{ parameters.svc_value_File }}'
      condition: and(succeeded(), ne('${{ parameters.new_tag_value }}', ''))
```

Comment: Hi there, I defined a parameter `tag_value` with `default: ''` in the upstream YAML and transferred into template YAML by `new_tag_value: ${{ parameters.tag_value }}`; the step in the template YAML was skipped as expected saying `Skipping step due to condition evaluation.` For this, can you please share your minimum upstream YAML context to reproduce your issue? It will help understand how the value is defined/generated in the upstream YAML and transferred to the template YAML. Thx

Answer (score 0):

When the parameter is null, the check compares null with an empty string. Null is not equal to an empty string, the ne expression therefore evaluates to true and executes.

Comment: The same condition works outside the template. If I add the condition in the main pipeline yaml instead of template it works. So ideally if its taking it as null it should also not work if used in main pipeline yaml right

Comment: Tried with Null but it does not work still

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the sample below to update your YAML files to make the condition work as expected in the pipeline.

###### The template YAML file: **`Steps_Temp/insert-step.yml`**

```yaml
parameters:
- name: new_tag_value
  type: string

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'A template step'
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne('${{ parameters.new_tag_value }}', ' '))
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      echo "This is a template step."
      echo "new_tag_value = ${{ parameters.new_tag_value }}"
```

###### The main YAML file: **`azure-pipelines.yml`**

```yaml
parameters:
- name: MyTag
  type: string
  default: ' '

stages:
- stage: A
  displayName: 'Stage A'
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    displayName: 'Job A1'
    steps:
    - template: Steps_Temp/insert-step.yml
      parameters:
        new_tag_value: ${{ parameters.MyTag }}
```

###### Result

- When triggering a new run of the pipeline, if directly using the **`default`** value of **`MyTag`** and providing a new value, the **`Bash@3`** task will be skipped.
- When triggering a new run of the pipeline, if providing a new value which is not null or whitespace to **`MyTag`**, the **`Bash@3`** task will run.